# Создание круглых кнопок во время выполнения Android-приложения

Tags: android

Нужно создать на экране круглую кнопку, такую как мы можем видеть в приложении Google+ и других приложениях с Material Design. При том что сделать это нужно во время выполнения программы по нажатию на другую кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/231429/

```
FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this) 
.withDrawable(yourDrawable) 
.withButtonColor(Color.WHITE) 
.withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT) 
.withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16) 
.create();
```

Или вот https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton